# Cannot Navigate using Controller/Action in Navigation Bar

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am working in an ASP.NET MVC 4 project.  I did not create this project, but whomever did, fixed it so that I cannot put the ControllerName/ActionMethod in the navigation bar to navigate to any page/view in the project (including any new view/page that I create).  Given that I cannot navigate to new views/pages that I create myself, I am assuming that there must be some sort of global setting to prevent this, but I am new to MVC and can't figure out where to look or what to look for.  Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure this out (not completely, but enough to make it work).  I needed to add
[Authorize] above the public class Controller.  Hope this helps someone else!